# Understanding Foreign Key definitons in SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to construct a regular "plain-old nothing fancy" foreign key relationship between two tables in SQL Alchemy.

This is the code I have come up with in order to do that:

```
class Ticker(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ticker'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    ticker: Mapped[str]
    type: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('ref_data.ticker_type.id'))
```

which references the table

```
class TickerType(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ticker_type'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    ticker_type: Mapped[str]
```

There's a couple of things about this which seem sub-optimal, and I'm wondering if there's a better way to specify the foreign key.

1. The Foreign Key should "pick-up" the column type from the column type being referenced. However, here I had to specify the type hints manually. With the latest versions of the SQL Alchemy ORM, we do not have to specify the data type of a column directly, as it can be inferred from the type hint information, if we provide type hints. (Which we want to do because it improves integration with IDEs, static type checkers, etc.)

For example, in these tables we used:

```
ticker: Mapped[str]
```

and

```
ticker_type: Mapped[str]
```

which contains type hinting information, which means we can ommit the entire `mapped_column` construct.

2. In order to actually "get to" the referenced column, I had to use a fully-qualified name, including the schema name: `ref_data.ticker_type.id`. I would have thought that since I specified the schema names already, as part of the `__table_args__` construct, the schema name should not need to be specified again.

The `__table_args__` is picked up from the base class.

```
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'ref_data'}
```

Is there an alternative way to define the Foreign Key construct which addresses one or both of the above issues?